# MSVC in Debug mode showing more allocations than RelWithDebInfo

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

- Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019 Version 16.11.8
- MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 build tools (latest)

I'm attempting to measure allocations using polymorphic memory resources (pmr), so I've written up some code:

```
std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource mbr;
std::pmr::pool_options opts{ sizeof(std::pair<const Int64, Order>) * 128, 1024 };
std::pmr::unsynchronized_pool_resource pool{ opts, &mbr };
std::pmr::unordered_map<Int64, Order> m( &pool );

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    m.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
        std::forward_as_tuple((Int64) i),
        // create an Order object with some dummy data
        std::forward_as_tuple(dummy_eos, 0, 0, 0, 0, dummy_ai));
}

m.clear();
```

I've set breakpoints on the line where `m` is constructed and on the last line (before `clear` is executed).

In Debug mode, running the Visual Studio heap profiler:

[image]

[image]

When I run the same unaltered code on RelWithDebInfo, I get measurement data that I expect:

[image]

Although when I open the snapshot data, I don't see my `std::unordered_map` objects anymore. In other words, the Debug snapshots showed list nodes, container proxy, etc. object, but the RelWithDebInfo snapshots don't.

**Question:**
Why is Visual Studio reporting allocations every time I emplace a KV pair into the map in Debug mode? Shouldn't the memory be pooled like in the RelWithDebInfo snapshot?

Comment: MSVC standard library implementation enables heap overruns checks in debug builds.  You can try to build with [_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL=0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/iterator-debug-level?view=msvc-160) defined. Maybe it will make Debug behavior match Release here.